# Sort List of comma separated, pipe delimited records

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list where each item in the list is composed of two strings and an integer that are comma-separated, the structure of the list is given below:

```
Category, Subcategory, count
Category, Subcategory, count
```

And here's a simplified version of my unsorted list:

```
Honda, Accord SE, 322 
Honda, Civic, 69 
Real Estate Service,Yes, 701 
Honda, Ridgeline, 47 
Honda, Accord SE, 238 
Real Estate Service,No, 54
```

I can sort my list: `someList.Sort()`.

This will sort the list by Category, Subcategory, then count, each item in ascending order.

Is there a way to sort the list by Category then by Count?

And where two categories and subcategories are the same, keep the one with the highest count and remove the other(s)?

I've seen examples where each record could be a class with properties for the Category, Subcategory, and Count and a compare method written to compare records or using LINQ/Lambda expression but is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Can you upload a simplified version of your code/data structure ?

Comment: Here's a simplified version of my unsorted list:

Honda, Accord SE, 322

Comment: Here's a simplified version of my unsorted list:

Honda, Accord SE, 322
Honda, Civic, 69
Real Estate Service,Yes, 701
Honda, Ridgeline, 47
Honda, Accord SE, 238
Real Estate Service,No, 54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` and its `OrderBy`, `ThenBy`, `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending` methods:

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    // category, subcategory, count
    "A,Z,3",
    "B,Y,2",
    "C,X,1"
};

// ascending order
var orderedListAsc = list.OrderBy(x => x.Split(',')[0]) // order by category
                        .ThenBy(x => x.Split(',')[2])  // then order by count
                        .ToList();

// descending order
var orderedListDesc = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Split(',')[0])
                         .ThenByDescending(x => x.Split(',')[2])
                         .ToList();
```

As [Mark Balhoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3076048/mark-balhoff) pointed out in the comments, you probably would want to convert the `count` value to integer right before any sorting is done, as otherwise it would just compare string values.

```
.ThenBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[2]))
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to convert the count to a number to properly sort?

Comment: Yup, you are right. Thank you for pointing that out. I edited my answer. :)

Comment: That's it! Thank you ... really appreciate it.

Comment: Actually, this is what I need (just a small tweak):  

    `var proposalsSorted = proposals.OrderBy(x => x.Split(',')[0])
                                                          .ThenByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[2]))
                                                          .ToList();`  

Thank you! Much appreciated.